# Refresh Power BI dataset through Azure Data factory

Tags: powerbi, azure-data-factory

Is there a way to refresh Power BI dataset through Azure Data factory?

I found out that there is one REST API (https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-data-refresh-apis-in-the-power-bi-service/), which can be used to do this task but I am struggling to authenticate and pass an authorization token for the same.

Please suggest what other alternate options do we have?

Comment: It will be helpful if you share what you have tried so far and the exact error you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to refresh my Power BI dataset from Azure Data Factory using Power BI REST API's (POST/GET), the challenge was to pass an authentication token so that I figured out can be done by capturing "access_token" in a separate activity and then pass it to the POST activity which actually refreshes the dataset.

Here is the flow:

1. Web Activity to get the **token_type** and **access_token**. I had to pass various parameters to pipeline (refer screenshot below).

URL:  https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token

[image]

2. Another WEB activity to call POST API to refresh the dataset. In this I have passed the authentication tokens captured in previous Login Web activity (refer screenshot below):

[image]

Hope this helps!!

Feel free to reach out in case of any questions.

Comment: Looks good,,,Do you know how to get the token with Certificate instead of client secret

Comment: Sorry, haven't tried that @sangeethsasidharan!!

Please accept this as an Answer if it helped you so that others can get benefit from it as well.

Comment: i am having the same issue. I can get the token but when I pass it to refresh the Power BI dataset, I get the following error   
Invoking Web Activity failed with HttpStatusCode - '401 : Unauthorized', message - ''

Comment: @AnkurAggarwal  guidance needed

Comment: Hi @user1388142, 
Are you able to use Postman and try refreshing the Power BI dataset manually using the same token you have received as an output from data factory?

Answer (score 0):

Currently Azure Data Factory [supports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity#authentication) only `Basic` and `Client certificate` authentication:

> Authentication method used for calling the endpoint. Supported Types are "Basic, or ClientCertificate."

Comment: Hi Andrey, I was looking to authenticate Power BI REST API to refresh my dataset from Azure Data Factory. This is different from "Basic" or "Client certificate" type authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Matter of fact, there is an APP implementing REST API in Azure Logic Apps. You can invoke the logic app from the Azure Data Factory then. There is, however, one caveat. Number of refresh requests in last 24 hours are limited to 8 in the premium account - As mentioned in the REST API documentation [here](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-data-refresh-apis-in-the-power-bi-service/).

This is how it looks like in my Logic App Designer.

[image: This is how it will look like in the Logic App Designer]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

While most of the answers that I found on the web suggest to use app registrations / service principles, logic apps or even azure functions, I figured out a way to skip all that. I have actually written a [blogpost](https://www.tackytech.blog/how-to-refresh-power-bi-datasets-from-data-factory-with-managed-identity/) about this.

Essentially, it is pretty similar to the app registration approach and it uses even the refreshes-PBI API, but instead of adding an app's ClientID/ApplicationID to the security group, you can just use the data factory's managed identity. With that, a token retrieval (plus secret in key vault) is not needed either. Just follow these steps:

1. Create a security group in Azure and add the managed identity of the data factory to it
2. Align Power BI tenant settings to allow service principles to use APIs and add security group to be able use these settings. Also, add service principal to workspace.
3. Build web activity in Azure Data Factory pipeline as seen in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Axzcu.png) or here:

URL : [https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/[workspaceID]/datasets/[datasetID]/refreshes](https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/%5BworkspaceID%5D/datasets/%5BdatasetID%5D/refreshes)

Method :  Post

Body : {“notifyOption” : “NoNotification”}

Authentication : Managed Identity

Resource : https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api