# Is there a way to save Data Factory web activity output to a file or database table?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, token, azure-data-factory

I am hitting an issue in Data factory when connecting to oauth 2 rest api, where I don’t seem to be able to find a way to save the web activity output to a file or database table, so then other pipelines can do a lookup to get the current access and refresh tokens. As you can see in the attached scheenshot, I can connect to the api and get the access and refresh tokens back in ADF, now I want to store these somewhere, but its seems you can only save datasets in ADF and this is just the output of the web activity and can’t be made into a dataset. I can set them to variables, but this still doesn’t let me save them anywhere. Does anyone know a way of pushing these token values somewhere, either a file in data lake or database table?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Screenshot added of pipeline using a stored procedure to stored the auth tokens to a database table.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/75zoi.png

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to store these token values. The output of "GetAccess_Token" web activity can be passed as input to the other activity like **activity('Get Access_Token').output.access_token**. Please refer my answer in another similar post of mine here ([Refresh Power BI dataset through Azure Data factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55643855/refresh-power-bi-dataset-through-azure-data-factory/55821044#55821044)).

Hope this helps!!

Please mark it as answer so that other people can get benefit from it.

Comment: Hi @AnkurAggarwal, thanks for your response, this helps but still wouldn't let me use the token values in other pipelines, the output.access_token value would only be available at that pipelines run time. I have now been able to store the values to a database table using a stored procedure activity that passes the output.access_token and refresh_token values to the sproc and stores them in an auth table. Other pipelines can then do a lookup on this table to get the current access tokens for the relevant api. Thanks again for you help.

Comment: Hi @Jase, I see what you were looking for and I am glad that my post helped you a bit to reach to your solution.
But just FYI, the access_tokens or refresh_tokens does get expire in some time so be aware of it when referring in other pipelines.